# Ajax: How to use a variable in the data field

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a ajax function which gets some graph data from a database.
It works fine but I want to make it generic.

```
function getGraphData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { action: "databaseName" },
        success: function (response) {
            //Some code;
        }
    })
}
```

So to make the function generic I need to pass a database name to the function instead of hard code it but I can't seems to get it to work.

I changed the code to this:

Function call:

```
 var dbname = "action: " + "mydatabase";
 getGraphData(dbname);
```

Changed function:

```
function getGraphData(database) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: database,
        success: function (response) {
            //Some code;
        }
    })
}
```

Where do I go wrong ??

Regards
Flemming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `"action: " + "mydatabase"` doesn't create an object, it creates a string. The output of that would be:

```
"action: mydatabase"
```

What you want is the following:

```
{ "action" : "mydatabase" }
```

You need to do something like:

```
var dbname = { action :"mydatabase" }
```

Combining your function into a full example, it would be like this:

```
var database_name = "database1";
var data = { action : database_name }

getGraphData(data);  
// Your original function
function getGraphData(database) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: database,
        success: function (response) {
            //Some code;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Spot on.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getGraphData(database) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {action: database},  <-- change this line
        success: function (response) {
            //Some code;
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing just the value

```
getGraphData("mydatabase"); 

function getGraphData(database) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { action: database },
    success: function (response) {
        //Some code;
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the full object:

```javascript
db = { action: "myDatabase" };
getGraphData(db);

function getGraphData(dbObject) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: dbObject,
        success: function (response) {
            //Some code;
        }
    })
}
```

OR (if the object is always the same) simply pass the actual database name:

```javascript
name = "myDatabase";
getGraphData(name);

function getGraphData(dbName) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { action: dbName },
        success: function (response) {
            //Some code;
        }
    })
}
```